# WS-I Basic Profile about soap:body

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, ws-i

I'm kinda new to SOAP.

In my WSDL, I've got a `message` element composed of several `part` elements. In the `binding` part of my WSDL, if the `soap:body` element does not include any `parts` attribute, I get the WS-I Basic Profile compliance error BP2119:

`A document-literal binding which does not specify the parts attribute, has more than one wsdl:part in the associated wsdl:message element.`

I read in some docs that if no `parts` attribute is specified, it is considered that all `part` elements are included in the binding, but I'm guessing this assertion does not take into account the Basic Profile compliance. I therefore added a `parts` attribute with all the message's parts:

```
<soap:body parts="cpName fpList" use="literal"/>
```

But then, I'm getting the BP2111 error:

`One or more soapbind:body element(s) in a document-literal soap:binding does not have at most one part listed in the parts attribute.`

So, I have to specify the parts, but I can put only one? Aren't these two errors contradictory? How do I get away with that?

Alternatively, do I have to be Basic Profile-compliant? If not, how do I deactivate these checks in axis2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some answers here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-usagewsdl/

In bulk, document-literal wrapped pattern doesn't authorize several parts for one message. A message has to be composed of only one part, whose type will be an XS element who itself can be composed of multiple elements.